# Select elements in an array that satisfy a criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

**The goal: Kappa-Sigma clipping in Excel**
I want to implement a selective linear regression formula in Excel (avoiding VBA). I have a data sample on which I need to apply a linear regression. But my data has some structural outliers. I want to filter them out using a [kappa-sigma clipping](http://www.insight-journal.org/browse/publication/132). Basically this just does a linear regression, calculates the error per datapoint and if a datapoint had a large error (some constant [kappa] times the standard deviation of all errors [sigma]), it will be rejected from the next iteration. Then the linear regession is applied again on the clipped dataset.

**What I have so far**
I have an Excel sheet with dummy data (y = 3 * x + some error). Three datapoints (x = 6, x = 10 and x = 16) have a structural (measurement) error. So I fit the data (`A25:C29`), calculate the error (column D) and check if the error is bigger than kappa (1) times the standard deviation of the error's (`B31`). The results are in column E. You can see that the three datapoints with the structural error are neatly identified.

[image]

**Where I'm stuck**
I want to do a linear regression again on the x's and y's *without* the data points that should be clipped. In the most ideal case, I'd like to enter the condition (`D2:D22<$B$31*$B$32`) directly into the `LINEST` formula, so I get the results without using intermediate columns (now in E:G). I'm pretty sure that this can be done using some condition and using array functions, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Looks like G25:H29 are failing to calculate - this is because of the null values in F and G in rows 8,12 and 18 yes? So in order to get your current `linest` in F/G you would need to combine the four groups of data in F/G to exclude blanks? This is what you want to do, but without the need for E,F,G - right?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want to do. The NULL values indeed prevent the correct calculation of linest.

Comment: I just had a small moment to look at it. It gives a result (no errors) and the idea definitely works; smart use of array functions - I didn't know that the second argument of OFFSET could be an array. The resulting a is around 0,3. That's definitely wrong. a should be around 3. I'll take a look at it, but right now I have to attend to a 3-year-old hanging on my leg... ;-)

Comment: Try this for G25 `=LINEST(N(OFFSET(G2:G22,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(G2:G22),ROW(G2:G22)-ROW(G2)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(G2:G22)))),0,1)),N(OFFSET(F2:F22,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(G2:G22),ROW(G2:G22)-ROW(G2)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(G2:G22)))),0,1)))` - I get around 3

Comment: It should also work for `#N/A` which we can get with `F2=IF($E2,LOOKUP(1,2),A2)` and `G2=IF($E2,LOOKUP(1,2),B2)`. This means we can work with #N/A errors, I think that can help us link back to the true/false

Comment: You could hide the rows having a large error: Highlight the error column, click the banner `Data > Filter`, click the small triangle displayed at bottom right corner of the column, in the drop-down menu choose `Number Filter > Custom Filter`, then set your condition.

Comment: @harrymc that doesn't work because it doesn't exclude the data from the linest calculation...

Comment: Why not just copy visible cells to a new sheet? Go to quick access tool bar drop down → more commands → commands not in the ribbon → select visible cells → add. When you click this it will select everything that is visible and you can copy and paste it.

Comment: @harrymc: my real data are timeseries. I need to run that continuously as new data are automaticaly added. This makes such a manual solution not feasable. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I imagine VBA will be a much easier solution

Comment: Yes, one could automate the above procedure (or some variant of it) as a macro.

Comment: One can also, instead of copy-paste, delete the filtered/hidden rows : [How to delete all hidden rows or columns in Excel](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/857-excel-delete-hidden-rows-columns.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHA! Here's your dang monster array formula:

```
{=LINEST(N(OFFSET(B2:B22, SMALL(IF(ABS(D2:D22)<=B31, ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2)), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIFS(D2:D22,"<="&B31,D2:D22,">=-"&B31)))), 0, 1)), N(OFFSET(A2:A22, SMALL(IF(ABS(D2:D22)<=B31, ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2)), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIFS(D2:D22,"<="&B31,D2:D22,">=-"&B31)))), 0, 1)))}
```

It looks like some of the ones in the comments but I had to tweak it a bit. The main thing is that the comments use `ISNUMBER` to determine if we want to use a value and `COUNT` to determine how many we want in total. I changed those to evaluate the `error` field compared to the Std Dev value using `IF(D2:D22<=B31` and then count them based on the same criteria using `COUNTIF(D2:D22,"<="&B31)`.

Note that I wrote the formula using cell references based on your sheet so be careful if this is some mockup and your actual sheet has values in different ranges.

`2.798424149` = Correct Value (based on your clipped ranges)
`2.798424149` = Value given by my formula
`2.825623377` = Value given by a formula that doesn't ignore the ones with high error

By the way, the reason the formula you tried kept giving you `0.329988513` is because you had the X and Y references reversed. I assume wherever you copied the formula from had their sheet setup in the reverse order from your own.

---

Bonus thought: If you really really want, you could drop the `a*x+b` and `error` fields in addition to the rest and this formula could be tweaked to still work. You may want to keep those fields for other reasons, though, in which case the formula as is will be fine.

If you want to drop the `error` field:

```
{=LINEST(N(OFFSET(B2:B22, SMALL(IF(ABS(B2:B22-C2:C22)<=B31, ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2)), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUMPRODUCT(1*((B2:B22-C2:C22)<=B31)*((B2:B22-C2:C22)>=-B31))))), 0, 1)), N(OFFSET(A2:A22, SMALL(IF(ABS(B2:B22-C2:C22)<=B31, ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2)), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUMPRODUCT(1*((B2:B22-C2:C22)<=B31)*((B2:B22-C2:C22)>=-B31))))), 0, 1)))}
```

If you want to drop both the `a*x+b` *and* the `error` fields:

```
{=LINEST(N(OFFSET(B2:B22, SMALL(IF(ABS(B2:B22-(B24*A2:A22+C24))<=B31, ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2)), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUMPRODUCT(1*((B2:B22-(B24*A2:A22+C24))<=B31)*((B2:B22-(B24*A2:A22+C24))>=-B31))))), 0, 1)), N(OFFSET(A2:A22, SMALL(IF(ABS(B2:B22-(B24*A2:A22+C24))<=B31, ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2)), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUMPRODUCT(1*((B2:B22-(B24*A2:A22+C24))<=B31)*((B2:B22-(B24*A2:A22+C24))>=-B31))))), 0, 1)))}
```

Are you feeling it now, Mr. Krabs?

Comment: Looks like you nailed it. I'll take a closer look at it this weekend and award you the very deserved points if it works. I think I'll accept this answer (instead of your other answer). Although this one is more conplex, it is the better fitting answer to my original question...

Comment: ...is that a spongebob reference totally off topic but still Mr. Krabs??

Comment: @NathanTaylor I'm just feeling hyped about it. I spent about an hour pondering out the solution and, as I showed how you could remove fields entirely from the data, the formula became even *more* of a monster. You should be excited about massive formulas doing super-complicated things.

Comment: Damn smart. +1, accepted and a bonus. Well deserved. Thank you very much; and thank you @Raystafarian for the initial approach. Seems only appropriate to finish this off with the very first line of Mr Krabs (pilot episode): "Well lad, it seems like you don't even have your sea legs." >8<

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding another two columns to the right to extract just the values you need in a compact form without any blanks at the end. Using your example, the formula for x & y would be:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($F$2:$F$22,ROW()-1),NA())
=INDEX($G$2:$G$22,MATCH($H2,$F$2:$F$22,0))
```

This extracts all the non-clipped x & y values without any blanks in between and the extra cells at the bottom showing errors. Then, make two named ranges using the following formula for x & y:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$H$1,1,0,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$22),Sheet1!$H$2:$H$22,0))
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$I$1,1,0,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$22),Sheet1!$H$2:$H$22,0))
```

This will select all the records in each of those two compact sections but not the error cells at the bottom. You can then use those two named ranges for `LINEST` and whatever else you like.

This creates a little bit larger spreadsheet but it's much easier to debug and I always prefer shorter formulas over shorter spreadsheets.

[image: Screenshot from Excel Showing Solution]

Comment: I know this uses extra columns and you said you don't want to but I don't see a formulaic way around it. I can get the array in order but I end up with trailing bits that I can't figure out how to remove.